# Как прикрепить кнопки на форму?

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кнопка должна быть сверху. Что необходимо сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кнопка создана программно (кодом), вызовите метод [BringToFront](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront?view=netframework-4.7.2).

---

Если кнопка добавлена в режиме дизайнера, нажмите на кнопку Bring to Front на панели инструментов Layout в Visual Studio.

Аналогичный пункт есть в контекстном меню (правый клик мыши на контрол).

Answer (score 0):

Желательно, конечно, поставить `BorderStyle` на `None` и создать свой UI (так же сделано в VS и во всех Office-прогах).